# Error in editing vimrc

Tags: vimrc, error

I wrote

`:e $MYVIMRC`

to edit my vimrc and after adding my edits. I wanted to save and exit
`:wq`
but then it says:

```
E505: C:.... is read only press ! to override
```

so I write `:wq!` but it doesn't exit the document and it says:

```
... E212 can't open file for writing
```

For Maxim
[image]

[image]

Comment: You’re in the right place :) welcome

Comment: All vimrc files are in incorrect locations again

Comment: @MaximKim I put it in ````C:\Users\username\vimfiles\vimrc```` as suggested

Comment: vimrc should be a file in vimfiles/ subfolder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you don't have local user `.vimrc`.

$MYVIMRC is pointed to the one that was used to initialize your vim. If there is no user `.vimrc` it would be system-wide one and usually you would have to edit it with superuser rights.

So in vim, do `:e ~/.vimrc` and add your settings there. Bear in mind there is also `defaults.vim` (`:h defaults.vim`) that is loaded if there is no user `.vimrc`... meaning you wouldn't get all the things from there unless you add them explicitly.

PS, better place for your settings is a `~/.vim/vimrc` if you plan to store you config on a github/gilab/whatever.

PPS, you have added `vimrc` file to a `vimfiles/vimrc/` folder and it should be `vimrc` in `vimfiles/`. Check `:h viminit`

```
II  The user vimrc file(s):
        "$HOME/.vimrc"     (for Unix) (*)
        "$HOME/.vim/vimrc"     (for Unix) (*)
        "s:.vimrc"         (for Amiga) (*)
        "home:.vimrc"      (for Amiga) (*)
        "home:vimfiles:vimrc"  (for Amiga) (*)
        "$VIM/.vimrc"      (for Amiga) (*)
        "$HOME/_vimrc"     (for Win32) (*)

----->  "$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc" (for Win32) (*) <----- HERE

        "$VIM/_vimrc"      (for Win32) (*)
        "$HOME/config/settings/vim/vimrc"   (for Haiku) (*)
```

[image]

Comment: I have looke in my C:\users foldder and youre right there is no local/personal vimrc . If I make a new folder and document for my vimcr, it will be blank - how will I add the things needed. On this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8rRV41-90Q&list=PL13bz4SHGmRxlZVmWQ9DvXo1fEg4UdGkr&index=13 it has a large if command which is what I saw in $MYVIMRC

Comment: On windows create a file `C:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/_vimrc` or `C:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/vimfiles/vimrc`

Comment: Done. Now, there is an error message when I open gvim that says ````Cannot source a directory: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc
"````

Comment: why did my vimrc not install when I installed gvim

Comment: @user716881 You should create a `vimfiles` directory, but `vimrc` inside it should be a **file**.

Comment: @I put my document ````vimrc.txt (blank)```` in my file ````vimrc````, I don't get that message anymore, but it is still empty should I copy&paste the if statement from ````$MYVIMRC```` into ````vim.txt````

Comment: @user716881 pls do what is suggested, i.e. put your settings into `vimfiles/vimrc` file, without any extension (no `.txt`). PS, you can join irc #vim on freenode to ask for the more interactive help

Comment: see my question edit. How o I make $MYVIMRC come here and should I copy and paste the 'if' statement or do I just add my additional settings. Secondly this new file is also readonly.

Comment: @user716881 updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this is not a part of the question but I get: ````Error detected while processing C:\Users\maria\vi
mfiles\vimrc:

line    5:

E518: Unknown option: 80

line    8:

E185: Cannot find colour scheme '= elflord'```` I wrote ````colorscheme=elflord```` and ````set colorcolumn = 80````

Comment: @user716881 you better ask another question... but don't use spaces around `=` with `set`, ex `set colorcolumn=80` and for colorscheme don't use `=`, `colorscheme elflord`

Comment: @MaximKim Thanks